# Trouble with environment variables in C#

Tags: c#

Please help, I have an error:

```
File.Copy(@"%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\UserData\Default\Bookmarks", @"%userprofile%\Music\Bookmarks", true);
```

C# can't see this path `:C`

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: What do you mean by " i need some error" ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use [`Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables.aspx) before using windows variable:

```
var path1 = @"%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\UserData\Default\Bookmarks";
var filePath1 = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(path1);

var path2 = @"%userprofile%\Music\Bookmarks";
var filePath2 = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(path2);

File.Copy(filePath1, filePath2, true);
```